# Ajuda com rotas ASP MVC (3 rotas para a mesma action)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rotas

Tenho um controler:

```
public class imoveisController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int idEstado = 0, int idCidade = 0, int[] idRegiao = null)
    {
        string IdEstado;
        string IdCidade;
        int[] IdRegiao;

        #LeOuGravaCookie

        #region MontaViewBags

        #region RetornaBairros

        #region RetornaImoveisDessesBairros

        return View(ImoveisRetornados);
    }
}
```

Na view há um formulário onde o usuário pode selecionar 1 estado e 1 cidade e um conjunto de bairros. E quando submetido retorna para a action Index que ao invés de ler esses dados de um cookie vai receber do formulário, fazer a busca e retorna os imóveis. Funcionando 100% certinho.

Meu problema é que ao retornar exibe para p usuário a seguinte url:

> meusite/imoveis

E eu preciso retornar dependendo do que o usuário selecionar no formulário
Se ele informou apenas o estado:

> meusite/imoveis/{estadoInformado}

Se ele selecionou também uma cidade:

> meusite/imoveis/{estadoInformado}/{CidadeInformada}

Alguém poderia me ajudar a fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a seguinte estratégia:

```
[RoutePrefix("home")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet, Route("inicio")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost, Route("inicio/{uf?}/{municipio?}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string uf, string municipio)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Busca", new { uf = uf, municipio = municipio });
    }

    [Route("busca/{uf?}/{municipio?}")]
    public ActionResult Busca(string uf, string municipio)
    {
        return View("Index");
    }    
}
```

Formulário com os campos:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
    <input name="uf" id="uf" type="text" />
    <input name="municipio" id="municipio" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="BUSCAR" />
}

//Lembrando que é necessário configurar os MapMvcAttributeRoutes no arquivo RouteConfig.cs
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Quando você submeter o relatório ele vai mandar para a `Action` Buscar com a nova URL.